# Cannot resolve iframes in VSCode using Puppeteer

Tags: visual-studio-code, iframe, puppeteer, vscode-extensions

I am working on testing a VSCode extension using Extension Development Host.

After selecting the iframe, I cannot resolve the content within the iframe:

```
await vscode.Page.waitForSelector('iframe');
const f = await vscode.Page.$("iframe.webview.ready");
const x = await f.contentFrame();
```

This is coming up as null. The iframe in question is as follows:

```
<iframe name="31af8060-a20c-43b5-9bc4-2e0907beb675" class="webview ready" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-downloads" allow="cross-origin-isolated; clipboard-read; clipboard-write;" src="vscode-webview://15p9bvij4mfrnhuk8i83rio1oji5609me4l6cj09abkcjtll7asl/index.html?id=e7e197b0-ad2f-4033-adc6-e0a045447be5&amp;origin=1b8ed955-2a8f-49d8-9f39-1c1d5b80e870&amp;swVersion=4&amp;extensionId=hehe&amp;platform=electron&amp;vscode-resource-base-authority=vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net&amp;parentOrigin=vscode-file%3A%2F%2Fvscode-app" style="border: none; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: auto;"></iframe>
```

While Chrome has a argument for --disable-web-security, VSCode does not have anything of that sort. Also, I am not sure if that is the problem here. Any sugestions?

selector.contentFrame() is supposed to resolve the iframes. But when that wasn't working as expected, I found that it could be an issue regarding same origin policy in Chrome and can be bypassed by --disable-web-security.

But VSCode does not have such an option, even though it is built on the Chromium platform. Unable to find the resolution in this situation.

Comment: where is this `vscode.Page` documented

Comment: We arrive at [page](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page) using:

`class VSCode{
  this.Browser = await puppeteer.connect(connectOpt);
  const contexts = await this.Browser.browserContexts();
  const ct1 = contexts[0];
  const pages = await ct1.targets();
  for(const page of pages){
    //based on condition
    this.Page=page;
  }
}`